# Problema posicionamiento de cards en ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, map, card

estoy mappeando una lista de productos con una card pero al momento de hacerlo, me salen en vertical y quiero que sea horizontal.

```
///card
import React from 'react'
import StyleContainer from '../subcomponentes/Stylecontainer';
const Card = (props) => {
    return (
        <>
           <div className="col-xl-12"> 
                <h5 className="mt-4">Card Columns</h5>
                <hr />
                {/* <div className="card-columns"> */}
                
                    <div className="card">
                        <img className="img-fluid card-img-top" src="assets/images/slider/img-slide-1.jpg" alt="Card image cap" ></img>
                        <div className="card-body">
                            <h5 className="card-title">{props.nombre}</h5>
                            <p className="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                            <button className="btn  btn-primary">View More</button>
                            <button className="btn  btn-danger">Delete</button>
                        </div>
                       
                    </div>
                    </div>
            </>
    );
}

export default Card;


//listar productos
  return (
        <>
            <Header />
            
                    <div className='col-md-4'>
                   
                        {dataProductos.map((miproducto) => {
                            return (
                                <Card nombre={miproducto.nombre} />
                            )
                        })

                        }
                    </div>
            
               
                </>
         );
```

imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Click derecho en la card y mira qué ha sido generado por el framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente la explicacion dada por @JorgeAlmada en la primera respuesta es la razon de tu error.

Mi respuesta solo es para darte una opcion mas de como corregir ese pequeño inconveniente:

Me inclino mas por utilizar el sistema completo [grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/grid/) de boostrap (rows and cols), basicamente por que te van a permitir aprovechar la separación entre cada una de tus columnas ya que agrega padding vertical y horizontal (gutter) de igual manera ese gutter es responsive:

Dejando tu codigo de la siguiente manera

```
return (
  <>
    <Header />

    <div className="row">
      {dataProductos.map((miproducto) => {
        return (
            <div className="col-md-4">
              <Card nombre={miproducto.nombre} />
            </div>
          );
      })}
    </div>
  </>
);
```

Logrando el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te dejo un pequeño [playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-elctmr?file=src/Card.js) para que lo pruebes:

Comment: bro si me funciono yo tenia un erro en el css..mil gracias

Answer (score 0):

Estás mapeando tus cards dentro de un contenedor con la clase *col-md-4*, esta clase no es flexible por naturaleza, además de que básicamente le estás diciendo que sólo el espacio de lo que serían 4 unidades en el sistema de grid de bootstrap (que está dividida en 12 espacios); en palabras más simples, tu contenedor no está hecho para mostrar las cartas de la manera que tú quieres, ni va a obtener las dimensiones que necesitas 
La mejor manera de arreglarlo, es quitando esa clase que ya tiene, y agregando *col-md-12 d-flex* como clases del contenedor, tu componente para listar productos quedaría así

```js
//listar productos
  return (
        <>
            <Header />
            
                    <div className='col-md-12 d-flex'>
                   
                        {dataProductos.map((miproducto) => {
                            return (
                                <Card nombre={miproducto.nombre} />
                            )
                        })

                        }
                    </div>
            
               
                </>
         );
```